# How to change path in neo4j

Tags: path, neo4j, graph-databases

I installed neo4j on Ubuntu and I wrote a code in Java to add nodes. When I run the server, the default path in the Neo4j is "/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db", but I want change the path to "/home/user/Documents/neo4j/". How I change the default path?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default db location by editing `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and 
updating
`org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db`

Comment: I changed to org.neo4j.server.database.location=/home/jessica/Documentos/neo4j/data/graph.db but now the server doesn't connect.

Comment: if you are in a mac, the folder "Documentos" is renamed by OS X just for presentation reasons, change the path to /home/jessica/Documents/neo4j/data/graph.db, that should work.